# Jmeter master slave in AWS on demand

Tags: amazon-ec2, jmeter

I was hoping to get some help/suggestions regarding my JMeter Master/slave test set up. 
Here is my scenario:
I need to do load testing using Jmeter master slave set up. I am planning to launch the master and slave nodes on AWS (window boxes, dependency on one of the tool I launch via jmeter). I want to launch these master-slave set up in AWS on demand where I can tell how many slave nodes I want. I looked around a lot of blogs around using Jmeter with AWS and everywhere they assume these nodes will be launched manually and needs further configuration for master and slave nodes to talk to each other. For the tests where we might have 5 or 10 slave nodes this will be fine but for my tests I want to launch 50 instances(again the tool I use with jmeter has limitation that forces me to use each jmeter slave node as 1 user, instead of using 1 slave node to act as multiple users) like this and manually updating each of the slave nodes will be very cumbersome. So I was wondering if anybody else ran into this issue and have any suggestions. In the mean time I am looking into other solutions that will help me to use same slave node to mimic multiple users, which will help me to reduce the need to launch these many slave nodes.

Regards,
Vikas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen [JMeter ec2 Script](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2)? It seems to be something you're looking for.

If for any reason you don't want to use particularly this script be aware that [Amazon has the API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) to you should be able to automate instances creation by using a script [AWS Java SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/ec2/package-summary.html) or [Amazon CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

You can even automate instances creation using a separate JMeter script with either [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) 
or [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) (this approach will require a separate JMeter script of course)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri this is really helpful. Will look into the ec2 script first otherwise other options appear to be straightforward too. Thanks, sorry should have been able to find this on my own. :(